# how to use pinch to zoom exoplayer

Tags: android-studio, touch-event, exoplayer

I am using exoplayer for my streaming app. i would like to implement touch to zoom video player as we do in youtube. if user pinch the screen it will go to zoom mode we will use

```
   playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
```

else we will use

```
 playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT)
```

I have tried different method from youtube alas none of them worked for me. so i would be happy if some one explain and give me the answer on how to use swipe or pinch to zoom

added with , i have found a medium page explaining this but i have good knowlege only in JAVA and not in kotlin
https://medium.com/agile-freaks/exoplayer-pinch-to-zoom-functionality-bae397471c37
if some one is wellverse in kotlin can help me to decode kotlin code to java